# GLM, fitting previous response data as predictor variable in R to accomodate temporal autocorrelation

Tags: time-series, generalized-linear-model

I would like to know effect of planting cycle (categorize) and water depth (continuous) to snail weight. I monitored every week for 1 year (53 week data), 25 sites.
Snail weight of this week may be correlated with last week. To accommodate temporal autocorrelation, may I use snail weight of previous week as predictor variable?

I fit my model like this:

```
glm(SnailWeight ~ Cycle + Water + SnailWeightLastWeek)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to start with a model without the lagged component, hence something like
$$SW_{i,t} = \beta_0 + \sum_{q\in Categories} \beta_q Cycle_{q,i,t} + \beta_{q+1}Water_{i,t}+u_{i,t}$$
as you do not know whether there is a temporal correlation in the data. Then you can have a look at the residuals $\hat{u}_{i,t}$ and start with a visual analysis via plotting the time series of resiudals. If there are some patterns you might consider doing something like
$$\hat{u}_{j,t} = \gamma_{0,j} +\rho_j \hat{u}_{j,t-1}+ \eta_{j,t}$$
for all $j$ sites.
In case that some of the $\rho_{j}$'s are significant you could rebuild your model by employing 
$$SW_{i,t} = \beta_0 + \sum_{q\in Categories} \beta_q Cycle_{q,i,t} + \beta_{q+1}Water_{i,t}+\beta_{q+2}SW_{i,t-1}+\epsilon_{i,t}.$$

Then you can check the residuals again in order to look whether the autocorrelation is gone. By this approach you not only detect the autocorrelation, but you also gain a sound reason, why to include the lagged response.

Comment: Thanks. So that, adding lagged component is a normal way in statistic. Is it ok if I use this method to other family, such as binomial or poisson?

Comment: You're welcome. Japp, in general it is not a problem is you add a lagged response also in other families.